# Search unix drive for file modified today

Tags: unix, search, date, date-modified

Is there a way I can search an entire unix drive for a file that was modified today? I realize this could take a while, but thats not an issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using the find command
`find / -mtime 0`

That will find all files with a modified date of 0 days, i.e. today.
If you have an idea of where the file may have been, or the name of it, then you can add extra parameters like so -
`find /home/ -mtime 0` to look for files in /home
`find / -mtime 0 -name filename` to look for files with a name of filename